# How to edit jupyter nbconvert templates

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter

I'm currently trying to change the looks of the nbconvert-output in jupyter. To be more precise, I want to convert a ipynb to latex but not using the default tamplate. The thing is I don't know how to edit the files to get the result I want.

Lets say I want to use the  "[style_notebook.tplx](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert-examples/tree/master/latex_cell_style)" so I need to donwload `ipython_nbconvert_config.py` and `use_cell_style.tplx`. After that I need to change in the `use_cell_style` file the second line to `((* set cell_style = 'style_notebook.tplx' *))`. But to be honest I don't know with what to edit a `.tplx` File (I used just Editor from Windows)....

After changing that and moving the two files to the same directonary as my `.ipynb` is, I tried this in the command prompt:

```
jupyter nbconvert --config ipython_nbconvert_config --to latex filename.ipynb
```

and got the error:

```
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | Error loading config file: ipython_nbconvert_config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 202, in load_config_file
    path=path
  File "<decorator-gen-5>", line 2, in load_config_file
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 603, in load_config_file
    self.update_config(new_config)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 198, in update_config
    self._load_config(config)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 168, in _load_config
    warn(msg)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 89, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1131, in hold_trait_notifications
    self.notify_change(change)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1176, in notify_change
    c(change)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 227, in _postprocessor_class_changed
    self.postprocessor_factory = import_item(new)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    return __import__(parts[0])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PDF'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Sito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\jupyter-nbconvert.EXE\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 252, in initialize
    self.init_postprocessor()
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 298, in init_postprocessor
    self._postprocessor_class_changed({'new': self.postprocessor_class})
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 227, in _postprocessor_class_changed
    self.postprocessor_factory = import_item(new)
  File "c:\users\Sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    return __import__(parts[0])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PDF'
```

So it says that I miss the PDF-module, but I'm not sure hows that possible, because until now I could convert to pdf just fine. So I aussume I made some mistakes in changing the files...

Would be nice if someone could explain how to fix this problem..

Thanks, Sito.